# How to use spinner for showing date in sql lite in android?

Tags: android, date, spinner, sqlline

I want to have 3 spinner in my app that are for date picking like this: Year – Month- Day For example, today is 2015-10-08 and spinners show this date automatically from system: 
year-spinner shows 2015 
Month-spinner shows 10 
Day-spinner shows 08 
Although users can change them with dropping down and selecting other one. At last these data must be save in my sql-lite data base. I don't know how to them, please help me.thanks!

This is my code:

my  app description is after AddVow is clicked, user add some data as number and date.number is taken by edit text and date is taken by spinner(as i describe above)

MyActivity.class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity   {

private ListView listView;
private AddVowAdapter adapter;
private DataBaseClass classDB;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

private ArrayList<String> vowId = new ArrayList<String>();  
private ArrayList<String> vow_number = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> vow_start = new ArrayList<String>(); 


private AlertDialog.Builder build;  // options for Edit/Delete


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    classDB =new DataBaseClass(this);

    // edit and delete code  
     listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,final int i,final long l) {
            // creating dialog
            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            //Edit
            build.setNegativeButton("ویرایش کردن نذز",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            Intent edit_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddVowActivity.class);
                            edit_intent.putExtra("id", vowId.get(i));
                            edit_intent.putExtra("number", vow_number.get(i));
                            edit_intent.putExtra("startDate", vow_start.get(i));
                             startActivity(edit_intent);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });


}


//***************** Menu Button for adding VOW
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_vow, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{   super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_vow_menu:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddVowActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("update",false);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}







@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}


private void displayData() {   //displays data from SQLite
    sqlDB = classDB.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DataBaseClass.VOW_TABLE_NAME, null);

    vowId.clear();
    vow_number.clear();
    vow_start.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            vowId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_ID)));
            vow_number.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_NUMBER)));
            vow_start.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_START_DATE)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    AddVowAdapter adapter = new AddVowAdapter(this,vowId, vow_number , vow_start);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCursor.close();
}
```

}

AddVowActivity.class:

```
public class AddVowActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private EditText addNUM;

private Spinner addYEAR;
private Spinner addMONTH;
private Spinner addDAY;

private Button insertBTN;
private Button deleteBTN;

private DataBaseClass classDB;
private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

private String id;
private String number;
private String startDate;
private String startDateFormat;
private boolean isUpdate;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_vow);

    classDB = new DataBaseClass(this);

    addNUM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addNum);
    addYEAR = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.addYear);
    addMONTH = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.addMonth);
    addDAY = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.addDay);

    insertBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    deleteBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBTN);


    isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("vowUpdate");
    if(isUpdate){
        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        number=getIntent().getExtras().getString("number");
        startDate=getIntent().getExtras().getString("startDate");

        addNUM.setText(number);

    }




insertBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        number=addNUM.getText().toString().trim();
        startDate= startDateFormat.trim();


    }
});



 //SPINNERS
    ArrayList<String> years=new ArrayList<String>();
    int minYear=2000;
    for(int i=minYear; i<=2020; i++){
        years.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> yearAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, years);
    addYEAR.setAdapter(yearAdapter);


    ArrayList<String> months=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
        months.add(String.format("%02d", i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> monthAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, months);
    addMONTH.setAdapter(monthAdapter);

    ArrayList<String> dates=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=1; i<=31; i++){
        dates.add(String.format("%02d", i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> dateAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dates);
    addDAY.setAdapter(dateAdapter);

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    addDAY.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)-1);
    addMONTH.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    addYEAR.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)-minYear);

    addDAY.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    addMONTH.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    addYEAR.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}








@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.addDay:

            break;

        case R.id.addMonth:// change accordingly dateadapter in based on month and year.
            break;
        case R.id.addYear:// change accordingly dateadapter in based on month and year.
            break;
    }

    String dayNO=addDAY.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String monthNo=addMONTH.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String yearNO=addYEAR.getSelectedItem().toString();


    Log.d("AddVowActivity", "onItemSelected :"+dayNO+"  "+monthNo+"  "+yearNO+"");

    // store your date format in your database here.
    startDateFormat = yearNO+ "-" + monthNo + "-" + dayNO;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}



private void saveData(){
    sqlDB=classDB.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_NUMBER,number);
    values.put(DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_START_DATE,startDate);
    System.out.println("");
    if(isUpdate)
    {
        //update database with new data
        sqlDB.update(DataBaseClass.VOW_TABLE_NAME, values, DataBaseClass.VOW_COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
    }else {
        //insert data into database
        sqlDB.insert(DataBaseClass.VOW_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    //close database
    sqlDB.close();
    finish();
}
```

}

AddVowAdapter.class:

```
public class AddVowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> VId;
private ArrayList<String> Vnumber;
private ArrayList<String> Vstart;

public ArrayList<Integer> selectedViewsPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public Cursor dbCursor;


public AddVowAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<String> number , ArrayList<String> start){
    context=c;
    VId=id;
    Vnumber=number;
    Vstart= start;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return VId.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (view == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vow_list_item, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mHolder.txt_VNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number_text);
        mHolder.txt_VStart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start_text);
        view.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.txt_id.setText(VId.get(i));
    mHolder.txt_VNumber.setText(Vnumber.get(i));
    mHolder.txt_VStart.setText(Vstart.get(i));


    return view;
}



public class Holder {
    TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_VNumber;
    TextView txt_VStart;
}
```

DataBaseClass.class:

```
public class DataBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static String DATABASE_NAME = "user's vowes";
public static final String VOW_TABLE_NAME = "vowing";
public static final String VOW_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String VOW_COLUMN_NUMBER = "number";
public static final String VOW_COLUMN_START_DATE ="startDate";

public DataBaseClass(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+VOW_TABLE_NAME+" " +
            "("+VOW_COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
            VOW_COLUMN_NUMBER+" TEXT, "+
            VOW_COLUMN_START_DATE+"  TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+VOW_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

and this is LogCat:

```
07-19 17:24:23.047    1884-2184/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice()                output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0
```

07-19 17:24:23.047    1884-2154/? D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA﹕ OutALSA::setDevice:           mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
   07-19 17:24:23.277   1884-16827/? V/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184

Comment: Yill now time nothing. I just find out getSystemDate from system. Would you please help me to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

```
public class SpinActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private Spinner spYear;
    private Spinner spMonth;
    private Spinner spDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_date);

        spYear = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_year);
        spMonth = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_month);
        spDate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_date);

        ArrayList<String> years=new ArrayList<>();
        int minYear=1980;
        for(int i=minYear; i<=2020; i++){
            years.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> yearAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, years);
        spYear.setAdapter(yearAdapter);


        ArrayList<String> months=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
            months.add(String.format("%02d", i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> monthAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, months);
        spMonth.setAdapter(monthAdapter);

        ArrayList<String> dates=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1; i<=31; i++){
            dates.add(String.format("%02d", i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dateAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dates);
        spDate.setAdapter(dateAdapter);

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        spDate.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)-1);
        spMonth.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        spYear.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)-minYear);

        spDate.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.sp_date:
                break;
            case R.id.sp_month:// change accordingly dateadapter in based on month and year.
                break;
            case R.id.sp_year:// change accordingly dateadapter in based on month and year.
                break;
        }

        String date=spDate.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String month=spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String year=spYear.getSelectedItem().toString();

       Log.d("SpinActivity", "onItemSelected :"+date+"  "+month+"  "+year);

        // store your date format in your database here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

layout (activity_spinner_date):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_year"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @KrishnaV.thanks for your answerbut i do not know how to save them in sql lite and show in my list view.(my app include edit texts and i don't know about spinner)

Comment: you just save it has string(yyyy-mm-dd) in your database and get that data and show it into listview.

Comment: That is my question. ?.how to pass it to listView and sqlLite??? (I want to use toString for make spinner items to string and pass it to them, but it does not work)....please...help me.

Comment: @KrishnaV.i post my code, but its result is app has been stopped...would you please help me to find out the problem?